# Expanding TableViewCells to match its content height

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I had a previous method that I will attach in the following sentence that managed to expand my tableViewCell from 55 to 240 when tapped. And when tapped again, it would return the UITableViewCell to its original height(55). This was my code and it worked completely fine:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
                return 240 //Expanded
            }
            return 55 //Not expanded
        }
```

However, I want my cell to expand to match the height of the content. Every cell contains a poem, and each poem has a different size logically. In my attempt to expand the cell to a match the height of the poem, I added a property of "type" to my coreData model. So if a poem had a value of "small" it would expand to 150, and if it had a value of "big" it would expand to 240 and so on. This was my code, however it isn't working.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex && arrayPoemas[indexPath.row].value(forKeyPath: "tipo") as! String == "grande" {
                return 240 //Expanded
            }
        else if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex && arrayPoemas[indexPath.row].value(forKeyPath: "tipo") as! String == "enorme" {
            return 320
        }
        else if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex && arrayPoemas[indexPath.row].value(forKeyPath: "tipo") as! String == "mediano" {
            return 150
        }
        else if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex && arrayPoemas[indexPath.row].value(forKeyPath: "tipo") as! String == "chico" {
            return 85
        }
            return 55 //Not expanded
        }
```

An error saying "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value" appears but I am sure that each single poem has a value for the property "type". How could i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expand the height of `UITableViewCell` according to the content size, just assign the bottom constraint of your your `Poem` with the bottom gf your cell. Cell will then take the height of the content inside it. For more details, look at this [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells)

As far as your crash goes, I will suggest you to debug the code, & look out for that part where you are force unwrapping string, which is never a good option.